# Conceptual question about extended affine Weyl group $\hat{W}_a$

Tags: group-theory, coxeter-groups

Denote an affine Weyl group by $W_a$, and let $\mathcal{H}$ be the collection of hyperplanes $H_{\alpha, k}, \text{ } \alpha \in \Phi,k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I know for a fact that $W_a$ and the extended affine Weyl group $\hat{W}_a$ permute the hyperplanes in $\mathcal{H}$. Moreover, $W_a$ simply transitively permutes the alcoves $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. the collection of connected components of $V \setminus \bigcup_{H \in \mathcal{H}} H $, where $V$ is the underlying vector space. But is this also necessary true for $\hat{W}_a$, that is, does it also simply transitively permute the alcoves? If so, or if not, then why?

Comment: Sorry I can't be more helpful, but $\widehat{W_a}$ does permute the alcoves, since elements of the affine group $\text{Aff}(V)$ act as homeomorphisms. However, I'm pretty sure it does not act simply transitively. I seem to remember there is a counterexample with $PGL_2$, but I can't recall the specifics at the moment.

Comment: It depends on what you mean "the alcoves": The extended affine group has its own system of alcoves (refining the one of $W_a$) which it permutes simply transitively. However, it does not even preserve the alcove system of $W_a$.  You can see this already in the $A_1$ case.