# Alcoves in extended affine Weyl group of $A_1^{(1,1)}$

Tags: group-theory, coxeter-groups

For affine Coxeter/Weyl groups, there is a standard representation into $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ (where $n$ is the rank of the Coxeter group) where the reflecting hyperplanes form a nice hyperplane arrangement $\mathcal{H}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the group acts on the connected components of the $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \mathcal{H}$. Additionally, this action preserves a family of planes. It is standard to take one of these planes and intersect it with $\mathcal{H}$ to obtain a collection of hyperplanes usually denoted $H_{\alpha,k}$, for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha$ a root in the underlying finite root system. Then the affine Coxeter group acts on the connected components of hyperplane complement of $\{H_{\alpha,k}\}$.

I was wondering if there is an analogous way of understanding the hyperplane arrangement and its complement for extended affine Weyl groups. Specifically, for the Weyl group corresponding to the $A_1^{(1,1)}$ root system is there a nice system of alcoves that the Weyl group acts simply transitively?

@Moishe Cohen mentioned in [Conceptual question about extended affine Weyl group $\hat{W}_a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240855/conceptual-question-about-extended-affine-weyl-group-hatw-a?newreg=5070b273297747deb2a8da55cea0bd55) that the extended affine Weyl group had its own system of alcoves refining the one of $\tilde A_1$.

Comment: What is $A_1(1,1)$? My favorite reference for the standard linear representation of a finitely generated Coxeter group is Bourbaki, Chapters 4-6 of Lie Groups and Lie Algebras. (Note that the Coxeter group there need not be finite.) You will find a system of alcoves, called chambers, there.

Comment: $A_1^{(1,1)}$ is the notation Kyoji Saito uses for the twice extended affine root system of $A_1$. In his 1985 paper, he defines extended affine root systems and then classifies them when the radical of the bilinear form is two-dimensional, sometimes referred to as elliptic root systems and elliptic Weyl groups. In general, extended affine Weyl groups are not Coxeter groups. However, Saito mentions that an extended affine Weyl group does act properly on a domain in the complexification of the real ambient space. Is this not what you were referring to in your previous comment I linked above?